# Django-allauth change redirect url when changing password

Tags: django, django-allauth

allauth redirects to login view when i change password. I need to change redirect url to index page. How to do it?

This is what i have so far:

views.py

```
def change_password(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return Http404
```

urls.py

```
url('^password/change/$', 'change_password', name='change_password'),
```

but it still redirects me to login page;/

Answer (score 3):

The working solution tested in `django v1.11.21` and `django-all-auth v0.39.1`:

First:

```
url(r"^accounts/password/change/$", CustomPasswordChangeView.as_view(), name="account_password_change")
```

Second:

```
from allauth.account.views import PasswordChangeView

class CustomPasswordChangeView(PasswordChangeView):
    success_url = '/' # <- choose your URL
```

That's all.

Comment: That's not all. You also have to override account/password_change.html, since it uses an explicit form action URL that points to the original view. So if you enter a wrong password, the original view is used.

Answer (score 1):

inside your app views.py file, override the PasswordChangeView of django allauth

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from allauth.account.views import PasswordChangeView


class LoginAfterPasswordChangeView(PasswordChangeView):
    @property
    def success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('generic:password_change_success')


login_after_password_change = login_required(LoginAfterPasswordChangeView.as_view())
```

in urls.py (where django allauth urls reside ).
this url shoul above comes above this (url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),) to override default change password behaviour

```
 url(r'^accounts/password/change/$', generic_views.login_after_password_change, name='account_change_password'), 

url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

this function for redirecting the after succefully change password.
here you have to create a html page with this name "password_change_success.html" in account template folder

```
@login_required
def password_change_success(request):
    template = "account/password_change_success.html"
    return render(request, template)
```

in url.py

```
url(r'^password_change_success/$', views.password_change_success, name="password_change_success"),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your views to:

```
def change_password(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/") //put the name of the url you want to change to within the quotes. As it stands, it will take you to, I'm assuming, what your homepage would be.
```

Make sure to import:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add a version where you need a dynamic URL and should instead override `get_success_url()`.

*views.py*

```py
from django.urls import include, path

from core.users import views as user_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/password/change/',
         user_views.CustomPasswordChangeView.as_view(),
         name='account_change_password'),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

*core/views.py*

```py
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse

from allauth.account.views import PasswordChangeView


class CustomPasswordChangeView(LoginRequiredMixin, PasswordChangeView):
    """
    Overriding Allauth view so we can redirect to profile home.
    """
    def get_success_url(self):
        """
        Return the URL to redirect to after processing a valid form.

        Using this instead of just defining the success_url attribute
        because our url has a dynamic element.
        """
        success_url = reverse('users:user-detail',
                              kwargs={'username': self.request.user.username})
        return success_url
```